# ClickOnce myApp.application generated with wrong PublishUrl

Tags: tfs, msbuild, clickonce

I have added a MSBuild target to update the PublishUrl and then call the 'Publish' target, passing the new value in. This has allowed me to build multiple branches and have the corresponding ClickOnce app dropped in a branch specific share location.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PublishUrl >\\someNetworkShare\</PublishUrl>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="PublishClickOnce">
    <PublishUrl>$(PublishUrl)$(BranchName)\</PublishUrl>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectPath)" Properties="PublishUrl=$(PublishUrl); PublishDir=$(PublishUrl); Platform=AnyCPU" Targets="Publish" />
</Target>
```

The problem is that this just doesn't work on one of my build machines. It works perfectly fine on 2 of them, but not the 3rd.

Looking at the myApp.application file i can see that the deploymentProvider codebase points to the unchanged PublishedUrl (but it has been updated at the time of calling the 'Publish' target:

```
<deploymentProvider codebase="file://someNetworkShare/myApp.application" />
```

The above should be:

```
<deploymentProvider codebase="file://someNetworkShare/branchName/myApp.application" />
```

A few things i have tried:

1. Update the 'InstallUrl' to match the 'PublishUrl'
2. Added logging to ensure that the 'PublishUrl' has updated before calling the 'Publish' target.
3. Added a condition to the 'PublishUrl' to only update if it is empty

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

-------------------------------- UPDATE --------------------------------

So a couple of things:

1. The working build machines are on W7, the failing machines are on a mixture of W7 and W8.
2. It turns out that you can exclude the deploymentProvider element (ProjectProperties -> Publish -> Manifest -> Exclude deployment provider URL). If excluded the system attempts to figure it out by its self at run-time (this is sufficient in most cases).
3. So I tested the build on a few more machines (a completely clean W7 VM, a W7 dev machine, W8.1 dev machine) and they both produced the incorrect deploymentProvider line.

   Still curious to the actual root cause of the issue so I don't want to mark it as answered.

Comment: Is Visual Studio installed on that defective build agent?

Comment: Not initially, but i have tried it with 2013, 2012 and with both installed.